# Assigning variables returned by Sklearn train_test_split()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, syntax

I was confused about using `train_test_split()` in sklearn. Here is a code snippet of something I've tried:

```
X = example_df.drop('features', axis=1)
y = example_df['price']

y_test, X_train, X_test, y_train= train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

How does it split the rows of `example_df`? `example_df` has 100 rows, so I expected the datasets to be split with the following sizes.

1. `y_test` should have 80 rows
2. `X_train` should have 20 rows
3. `X_test` should have 80 rows
4. `y_train` should have 20 rows

But the sizes of my datasets were, respectively: 20, 20, 80, 20.

Why is this?

Comment: train_test_split() returns the training data first, then the testing data, not the other way around. So you want `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(...)`

Comment: read documentation for [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) - even examples shows `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(...)` but you assign in different order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in this case, the correct order of variable assignment you should be using is
`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test`. i.e. you need to rewrite your code to be

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

**Multiple assignment unpacking**

Additionally, I suspect your confusion might also come from a misunderstanding of how multiple assignment unpacking in python works, and the return value of `train_test_split(...)`.

Let us consider giving `train_test_split(...)` a single array to split, e.g. `y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. `train_test_split(y)` gives us an output that will look something like `[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]` (plus or minus some shuffling). We see that it takes our original list and returns a **list of 2 lists**.

We can pass `train_test_split(...)` an arbitrary number of lists to split. So let's see what happens if we gave `train_test_split(...)` 2 lists (`list_1`, `list_2`) as input. It would return a **list of 4 lists**. The first two inner lists would be the training set of `list_1` followed by the testing set of `list_1`, and the last two inner lists would be the training set of `list_2` followed by the testing set of `list_2`. The returned lists however, are do not correspond to any keywords such as "X_train" or "x_test", they're just good old regular lists.

One way to handle the output would be like this

```
datasets = train_test_split(list_1, list_2)
list_1_train = datasets[0]
list_1_test = datasets[1]
list_2_train = datasets[2]
list_2_test = datasets[3]
```

However this is lengthy, repetitive, and prone to bugs. Thankfully, python gives us the syntax to unpack multiple variables and assign them in a single statement. The equivalent of assigning the four lists as shown in the above code snippet would be to do this:

```
[list_1_train, list_1_test, list_2_train, list_2_test] = train_test_split(list_1, list_2)
```

or with more [sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar):

```
list_1_train, list_1_test, list_2_train, list_2_test = train_test_split(list_1, list_2)
```